# What is the difference between "struct" and lack of "struct" word before member of a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have to create simple List implementation. They guy who wants that put `struct` before member `next` of class `Node`. Why is there a `struct` word, what would be the difference without it?

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;//what is this struct for?
};


struct List{
    struct Node *first, *last;
};
```

Comment: It's pointless cruft here.

Comment: It's a habit carried over from C.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, there is no need to use the `struct` keyword before the `next` declaration. It is usually considered a throw-back from C, where it is required. In C++, this would suffice:

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};
```

However, if you had a member called `Node`, then you *would* have to use `struct` or `class`:

```
struct Node{
    int Node;
    struct Node *next; // struct or class required here
};
```

You would also require `struct` of `class` for a declaration of a type that is not yet defined (a *forward declaration*). For example

```
struct Foo {
    class Bar* bar_; // Bar defined later
};
```

where I used `class` to show it makes no difference in this scenario.

Comment: That's better.  Glad someone saved this near trainwreck.

Comment: @JohnDibling I felt I had to intervene :-)

Comment: You might mention a forward declaration, ala `struct Node { struct FooBar* mFooBar; };`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `struct` before `next`. 
That should be a simple pointer to Node object.