# class myClass* holding; VS myClass* holding;

Tags: c++

I faced this in a code I was reading:

```
class myClass* holding;
```

Is this means the same as this below:

```
myClass* holding;
```

Thanks,
EK

Comment: Is there a prior declaration or definition of `class myClass` in scope?

Comment: Yes. The `class` may be necessary if there is something else called `myClass`, of if `class myClass` has not been previously declared. There are duplicates around.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501237/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-and-lack-of-struct-word-before-member

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate, since the only difference from the question @juanchopanza linked is the use of the `struct` class-key instead of the `class` class-key.

Comment: @Casey Well, there's another slight difference: the declaration is inside of a class/struct of the same type. That means the type has already been declared.

Comment: Thanks got it guys, sorry for duplication!

Comment: @formerRigger Nothing wrong with duplication - the more questions we have pointing at answers, the easier it is for the next person to find the answer they need. I'm not sure why the downvoters are beating you up about it.

Comment: Maybe they just like it. I lost those points that I wanted to make it to 20 so to go to the chat section, now lost points :/

Answer (score 2):

- If at that point `myClass` is known as a valid class name (i.e. it was declared before) then yes, both declarations are equivalent. It should be noted though that the class name can be hidden by, say, a variable name, in which case using the elaborated version `class myClass` will allow you to work around the hiding and make sure that you refer to the class name specifically, as in the following example

  ```
  class C {};

  int main() {
    int C;
    C a;       // <- invalid
    class C b; // <- OK
  }
  ```
- If at that point name `myClass` is not known, then the second version simply won't compile. The first version will compile and will introduce a forward declaration of `class myClass` (see LihO's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass* holding;
```

is rather equivalent to:

```
class myClass; // letting compiler know that there is type myClass
myClass* holding;
```

unless you are using `class` keyword to resolve the ambiguity of `myClass` *(see the other answer)*.

Comment: Thanks guys I got it now, pretty clear.